# Does Android support RFC 2821 SMTP standard?

Tags: android, smtp

Can anyone of you confirm me if RFC 2821 SMTP standard supported in Android?

Comment: The current RFC for SMTP is RFC 5321:  http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321

Answer (score 0):

From RFC 2821

> Abstract
>
> This document is a self-contained
>   specification of the basic protocol
>   for the Internet electronic mail
>   transport.  It consolidates, updates
>   and clarifies, **but doesn't add new or
>   change existing functionality    of
>   the following:**
>
> - the original SMTP (Simple Mail Transfer Protocol) specification of
>       RFC 821 [30],
> - domain name system requirements and implications for mail
>       transport from RFC 1035 [22] and RFC 974 [27],
> - the clarifications and applicability statements in RFC 1123
>     [2],
>       and
> - material drawn from the SMTP Extension mechanisms [19].

Notice where I've highlighted the text in **bold**. From that, I interpret that it is not a new standard nor does it add anything to the way SMTP works or any 'features' etc.

In short, I'd say the answer to your question is 'yes'. One thing to note, however, is that not every aspect of every internet protocol is compulsory. Don't ever assume that any platform which claims to conform to RFC xxxx actually implements all functionality. Anything that's defined to be optional may or may not be supported.